# mysql custom order by- dates

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with a col month listing all twelve months of the year. I would like to order this col with the current month at the bottom and then chronologically so if I ran the query now;

DEC

JAN

FEB

...

SEPT

NOV

Month is in the format MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(U.month, '%m'))

I adapted this from something I found on here but it only helps with ensuring the current month is listed last any ideas?

```
      ORDER BY (CASE 
           WHEN Month = MONTH(NOW())
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END ) ASC, month ASC
```

Comment: Is this a query you are going to be using repetitively in a production environment, or for some one-off reporting purpose?

Comment: well it will be used on the odd occasion so optimization isn't a huge concern, if that's what your getting at?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I asked.  If you would be doing regular queries on this the answer I would propose would include changing the field type.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY (CASE 
          WHEN Month = MONTH(NOW())
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END) DESC, month ASC
```

or:

```
ORDER BY (CASE 
          WHEN Month = MONTH(NOW())
          THEN 0
          ELSE 1
          END) ASC, month ASC
```

Either should do the trick.

Comment: thanks but both of those but the current month first(at the top) and the rest of the months don't desc above.

Comment: I've updated my orig post could it be that I've formatted the date causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with string values for your months, you can make this work with some slight modification.  You will likely either need to use full month names, or use the 3 letter abbreviations for all months (I wasn't quite sure what format you were using, since you examples showed abbreviations, yet you also mentioned `MONTHNAME()` which outputs the full month.  Here how it would work

For 3-letter month abbreviation:

```
ORDER BY (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`month`, ' 01 2012'), '%b %d %Y')) ASC
```

For full month name:

```
ORDER BY (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`month`, ' 01 2012'), '%M %d %Y')) ASC
```

This will convert the month value to a date (by adding day and year) and then sorting.

Comment: Thanks for that Mike but i get this error -                                 Incorrect datetime value: '1 01 2012' for function str_to_date

Comment: Sorry yes i'm using the full month name.

Comment: Ok so this works if     I use "ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Month, '%m') ASC;" but will it always place the current month at the bottom as its December I'm not sure if its ordered last because it the last month or because its the current month?